# Problema al obtener el valor devuelto de un Stored Procedure en .NET

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, .net, asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo un sistema el cual se registran por un formulario y al terminar les regresa el turno que les fue asignado, al probarlo por BD si funciona todo a la perfeccion, pero cuando trato de recuperar el valor devuelto por el Stored Procedure me marca el siguiente error:

> 09/03/2021 09:57:14 p. m. ==> SYSTEM.INDEXOUTOFRANGEEXCEPTION: BANDERA
> EN SYSTEM.DATA.PROVIDERBASE.FIELDNAMELOOKUP.GETORDINAL(STRING FIELDNAME)
> EN SYSTEM.DATA.SQLCLIENT.SQLDATAREADER.GETORDINAL(STRING NAME)
> EN SYSTEM.DATA.SQLCLIENT.SQLDATAREADER.GET_ITEM(STRING NAME)
> EN REGISTRO_VACUNACION_COVID_19.CONTROLLERS.VACUNACIONCONTROLLER.INSERTA_MASTER(REGISTRO X)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**El error ocurre en esta linea:**

```
 var bandera = Convert.ToInt16(reader["BANDERA"] == DBNull.Value ? 0 : reader["BANDERA"]);
```

Al revisar el código veo que esta bien escrito e nombre del campo devuelto por el SP. este es parte de mi codigo en C#

```
 public List<ERROR_BD> Inserta_Master(REGISTRO x)
    {
        List<ERROR_BD> l = new List<ERROR_BD>();
        try
        {
            if (x.TEL_CELULAR == null)
            {
                x.TEL_CELULAR = "0000000000";
            }
          
            var fech_nac = x.FECHA_NACIMIENTO.ToString("s");
            //var fech_in = x.m_agenda[0].FECHA_INICIO.ToString("s");
            //var fech_fin = x.m_agenda[0].FECHA_FINAL.ToString("s");
            #region consulta a la BD
            //var test= x.m_agenda[0].FECHA_INICIO.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm");
            SqlConnection sqlconn = conn.getConn();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "SP_REGISTRO";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NOMBRE", x.NOMBRE);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@APELLIDO_PATERNO", x.APELLIDO_PATERNO);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@APELLIDO_MATERNO", x.APELLIDO_MATERNO);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@COLONIA", x.COLONIA);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DIRECCION", x.DIRECCION);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CURP", x.CURP);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CP", x.CP);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TEL_CASA", x.TEL_CASA);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TEL_CELULAR", x.TEL_CELULAR);
            //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CORREO_ELECTRONICO", x.CORREO_ELECTRONICO);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FECHA_NACIMIENTO", fech_nac);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID_MODULO", x.ID_MODULO);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID_ACREDITACION", x.ID_ACREDITACION);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID_SECCION", x.ID_SECCION);



            cmd.Connection = sqlconn;
            if (sqlconn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                sqlconn.Open();
            }
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            // cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            #endregion



            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var bandera = Convert.ToInt16(reader["BANDERA"] == DBNull.Value ? 0 : reader["BANDERA"]);
                if (bandera == 0)
                {

                    ERROR_BD xx;

                    xx = new ERROR_BD();
                    xx.ErrorNumber = Convert.ToInt16(reader["ErrorNumber"] == DBNull.Value ? 0 : reader["ErrorNumber"]);
                    xx.ErrorState = Convert.ToInt16(reader["ErrorState"] == DBNull.Value ? 0 : reader["ErrorState"]);
                    xx.ErrorSeverity = Convert.ToInt16(reader["ErrorSeverity"] == DBNull.Value ? 0 : reader["ErrorSeverity"]);
                    xx.ErrorLine = Convert.ToInt16(reader["ErrorLine"] == DBNull.Value ? 0 : reader["ErrorLine"]);
                    xx.ErrorProcedure = (reader["ErrorProcedure"] == DBNull.Value ? "" : reader["ErrorProcedure"]).ToString();
                    xx.ErrorMessage = (reader["ErrorMessage"] == DBNull.Value ? "" : reader["ErrorMessage"]).ToString();

                    l.Add(xx);
                }
                else
                {
                    ERROR_BD xx;
                    xx = new ERROR_BD();
                    xx.BANDERA = Convert.ToInt16(reader["BANDERA"] == DBNull.Value ? 0 : reader["BANDERA"]);
                    xx.NO_TURNO = Convert.ToInt16(reader["NO_TURNO"] == DBNull.Value ? 0 : reader["NO_TURNO"]);
                    xx.FECHA_CITA = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["FECHA_CITA"] == DBNull.Value ? 0 : reader["FECHA_CITA"]);
                    l.Add(xx);
                }
            }
            if (l[0].BANDERA == 0)
            {
                log.ErrorLog("OCURRIO UN ERROR EN EL PROCEDIMIENTO: " + l[0].ErrorProcedure.ToString());
                log.ErrorLog("ErrorNumber: " + l[0].ErrorNumber.ToString());
                log.ErrorLog("ErrorState: " + l[0].ErrorState.ToString());
                log.ErrorLog("ErrorSeverity:" + l[0].ErrorSeverity.ToString());
                log.ErrorLog("ErrorLine: " + l[0].ErrorLine.ToString());
                log.ErrorLog("ErrorMessage: " + l[0].ErrorMessage.ToString());
            }

            sqlconn.Close();
            return l;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.ErrorLog(ex.ToString());
            return l;
        }

    }
```

Y este es el SP que tengo en la Base de Datos

```
                    USE [DB_CITAS]
                GO
                /****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[SP_REGISTRO]    Script Date: 09/03/2021 06:42:15 p. m. ******/
                SET ANSI_NULLS ON
                GO
                SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
                GO

                ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_REGISTRO]
                (@CURP varchar(18)
                           ,@NOMBRE nvarchar(50)
                           ,@APELLIDO_PATERNO nvarchar(100)
                           ,@APELLIDO_MATERNO nvarchar(100)
                           ,@COLONIA nvarchar(100)
                           ,@DIRECCION nvarchar(500)
                           ,@CP nvarchar(5)
                           ,@TEL_CASA nvarchar(10)
                           ,@TEL_CELULAR nvarchar(10)
                           --,@CORREO_ELECTRONICO nvarchar(50)
                           --,@FECHA_REGISTRO datetime
                           --,@FECHA_CITA datetime
                           ,@FECHA_NACIMIENTO datetime
                           ,@ID_MODULO int
                           ,@ID_ACREDITACION int
                           ,@ID_SECCION int
                           --,@ESTATUS char(1)
                           )
                AS
                BEGIN
                BEGIN TRAN
                BEGIN TRY
                --SE REALIZA LA OPERACION AQUI
                declare @fecha_reg datetime,@FECHA_CITA datetime ,@BANDERA_TURNO INT,@ID_REGISTRO INT 
                set @fecha_reg=(GETDATE());

                INSERT INTO [dbo].[REGISTRO]
                           ([CURP]
                           ,[NOMBRE]
                           ,[APELLIDO_PATERNO]
                           ,[APELLIDO_MATERNO]
                           ,[COLONIA]
                           ,DIRECCION
                           ,[CP]
                           ,[TEL_CASA]
                           ,[TEL_CELULAR]
                           --,[CORREO_ELECTRONICO]
                           ,[FECHA_REGISTRO]
                           --,[FECHA_CITA]
                           ,FECHA_NACIMIENTO
                           ,[ID_MODULO]
                           ,[ID_ACREDITACION]
                           ,[ID_SECCION]
                           ,[ESTATUS])
                     VALUES
                           (@CURP
                           ,@NOMBRE 
                           ,@APELLIDO_PATERNO 
                           ,@APELLIDO_MATERNO 
                           ,@COLONIA 
                           ,@DIRECCION
                           ,@CP
                           ,@TEL_CASA 
                           ,@TEL_CELULAR 
                           --,@CORREO_ELECTRONICO
                           ,@fecha_reg
                           --,@FECHA_CITA 
                           ,@FECHA_NACIMIENTO
                           ,@ID_MODULO 
                           ,@ID_ACREDITACION
                           ,@ID_SECCION
                           ,1
                           )
                --OBTIENE EL ID INSERTADO
                SET @ID_REGISTRO=SCOPE_IDENTITY()
                --MANDO LLAMAR EL SP QUE ASIGNA LOS TURNOS
                --Note that if you forget the OUTPUT keyword after the @count variable, the @count variable will be NULL.
                EXEC SP_ASIGNA_TURNO @ID_MODULO,@ID_REGISTRO,@BANDERA_TURNO OUT,@FECHA_CITA OUT

                --ACTUALIZA EL ESTATUS DEL REGISTRO
                if(@FECHA_CITA is NOT null)
                begin
                UPDATE REGISTRO SET ESTATUS=4,FECHA_CITA=@FECHA_CITA WHERE ID=@ID_REGISTRO
                end
                else
                begin
                --CITAS AGOTADAS PARA EL MODULO
                UPDATE REGISTRO SET ESTATUS=5 WHERE ID=@ID_REGISTRO
                end
                SELECT
                0 ErrorNumber,
                0 AS ErrorState,
                0 AS ErrorSeverity,
                '' AS ErrorProcedure,
                0 AS ErrorLine,
                '' AS ErrorMessage,
                1 as BANDERA,
                @BANDERA_TURNO as NO_TURNO,
                @FECHA_CITA as FECHA_CITA

                COMMIT;
                END TRY
                BEGIN CATCH
                --ATRAPA EL ERROR
                IF @@TRANCOUNT>0
                ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
                --SELECT 'Transaction is Rollback, In Catch Block';
                SELECT
                ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber,
                ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState,
                ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity,
                ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure,
                ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine,
                ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage,
                0 as  BANDERA,
                0 as NO_TURNO,
                NULL as FECHA_CITA;
                END CATCH

                END
```

Comment: La BD a la que estás apuntando desde el programa tiene ese mismo SP? tal vez entre BD local y otra hay diferencias en el SP aunque en ambas BD exista ese nombre de SP.

Comment: @ronpy al final, era por que el SP me devolvia dos cunsultas y como en la primera consulta no esraba el nombre de BANDERA pues por eso marcaba error , lo sulucion fue usar reader.nextresult()

Answer (score 0):

la solución fue usar reader.nextresult() ya que el SP me devolvía dos consultas.